# What is a good, inexpensive HTML editor with FTP support?

Tags: ftp, html, coda, bbedit

I just finished the two-week trial of Coda, and I really like it. The only issue is, I am a student, and the $99 license fee is a bit over my budget.

I do a lot of work on live sites, and an IDE with built-in FTP support really makes my workflow much faster.

My question is: Are there any free or cheap web code IDEs that have built-in FTP support? I have used TextWrangler, and that works passably. However, I would like something with an interface a bit more like Coda or HTML-Kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aptana Studio](http://aptana.com/products/studio3), based on Eclipse, has support for additional protocols, not just FTP. It's free.

Answer (score 0):

you could try Espresso (79 $) which is similar to Coda.

I use Flow (FTP) which has the ability to edit code directly in the app and to preview in real time. but there is no syntax highlighting or so.

Also I use Fraise which is my basic css/html/php editing program.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are going for free, I would suggest Eclipse. It is a very powerful editor, just a bit on the ugly side if you ask me.

As far as cheap goes, I would suggest BBEdit.  It is currently $50, but it is one of those tools that is well worth the money.  I use that almost exclusively for all of my development work.